# SwiftUI and UIKit: How to reload events data on UIViewRepresentable fetched from API with KVKCalendar library

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using [KVKCalendar](https://github.com/kvyatkovskys/KVKCalendar) with my SwiftUI application. I connected the UIKit library with bridge class called UIViewRepresntable. I have ViewModel which is fetching data from API and main class CalendarScreen which pushing the View.

CalendarScreen

```
struct CalendarScreen: View {
    @State private var updatedDate: Date?
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                CalendarDisplayView(events: $viewModel.events, updatedDate: $updatedDate)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                NavigationLink(destination: CalendarWriteScreen()) {  //Custom Action Button here }

                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 50, trailing: 20))
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                }
            }.onAppear {
                viewModel.fetchCalendarEvents()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

CalendarWriteScreen

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarWriteScreen: View {
    weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    @StateObject var viewModel = CalendarScreen.ViewModel()
    var eventId: Int?

    @State var eventData = CalendarEvent()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            ScrollView {
                // Some Struct that form Event
            }

        }.onAppear {
            if eventId != nil {
                viewModel.fetchCalendarEvent(eventId: eventId!)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Event")
    }

}
```

Bridge aka CalendarDisplayView

```
import EventKit
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarDisplayView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var events: [Event]
    @Binding var updatedDate: Date?
    private var calendar = CalendarView(frame: .zero)
    var selectDate = Date()
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CalendarDisplayView>) -> CalendarView {
        calendar.dataSource = context.coordinator
        calendar.delegate = context.coordinator
        calendar.reloadData()
        return calendar
    }
    func updateUIView(
        _ uiView: CalendarView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CalendarDisplayView>
    ) {
        context.coordinator.events = events
        calendar.reloadData()
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> CalendarDisplayView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    public init(events: Binding<[Event]>, updatedDate: Binding<Date?>) {
        self._events = events
        var style = Style()
        self._updatedDate = updatedDate
        selectDate = Date()
        var frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        frame.origin.y = 0
        frame.size.height -= 160
        calendar = CalendarView(frame: frame, style: style)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, CalendarDataSource, CalendarDelegate {
        weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?
        func eventsForCalendar(systemEvents: [EKEvent]) -> [Event] {
            // THIS FUNCTION SHOULD RELOAD MY EVENTS AND DISPLAY NEW EVENTS AFTER  CalendarWriteScreen dissappear
            return events
        }
        private var view: CalendarDisplayView
        var events: [Event] = [] {
            didSet {
                view.calendar.reloadData()
            }
        }
        var updatedDate: Date? {
            didSet {
                if let date = updatedDate {
                    view.selectDate = date
                }
            }
        }
        init(_ view: CalendarDisplayView) {
            self.view = view
            super.init()
        }
        func didSelectDates(_ dates: [Date], type: CalendarType, frame: CGRect?) {
            updatedDate = dates.first ?? Date()
            view.calendar.reloadData()
        }
        func didSelectEvent(_ event: Event, type: CalendarType, frame: CGRect?) {
            let screen = UIHostingController(rootView: CalendarWriteScreen(eventId: Int(event.ID)))
            view.calendar.parentViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(
                screen, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
func timeFormatter(date: Date, format: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder?.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
import Combine
import Foundation

extension CalendarScreen {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        let calendarService = CalendarService()
        @Published var calendarEvents: [CalendarEvent]
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
        init() {
            self.calendarEvents = [CalendarEvent()]
            self.calendarEvent = CalendarEvent()
            self.events = []
        }
        func fetchCalendarEvents() {
            cancellable = calendarService.getEvents()
                .sink(
                    receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                    receiveValue: {
                        calendarEvents in self.calendarEvents = calendarEvents
                        self.createEvents()
                    })
        }
        func createEvents() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.events = self.calendarEvents.compactMap({ (item) in
                    var event = Event(ID: String(item.id))
                    event.start = self.dateTimeFormat.date(from: item.start) ?? Date()
                    event.end = self.dateTimeFormat.date(from: item.end) ?? Date()
                    event.color = Event.Color(UIColor(InvoiceColor(title: item.title)))
                    event.isAllDay = false
                    event.isContainsFile = false
                    event.title = TextEvent(timeline: item.title)
                    event.data = nil
                    return event
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use .onDisappear function, tried to implement @State refresh variable but without proper funcionallity. Maybe i did something wrong.

One time i get in right and almost everything work but events get fetching everytime i clicked on View, so this implementation DOS attack on my local server. I added CalendarScreen.ViewModel to CalendarDisplayView and I implement function as follows:

```
func eventsForCalendar(systemEvents: [EKEvent]) -> [Event] {
    viewModel.fetchCalendarEvents()
    events = viewModel.events
    return events
}
```

I would like to refresh UIViewRepresentable and variable events located in class CalendarDisplayView everytime view CalendarWriteScreen appears or disappears so view will reload and event will fetch from API

Comment: It is a bit hard to follow because you have `Event` and `CalendarEvent` and you are also using `EKEvent`.  Regardless, because your calendar component is a UIKit component you can't rely on automatic updates from @Binding or @Published.  You can use a Combine subscriber to subscribe to the published events from your view model and update the calendar display

Comment: CalendarEvent is a entity that i created which contains [events] fetched from API. I am converting CalendarEvent to library Event so they can be visible on Calendar library. I dont really know why EKEvent is used maybe i can override it but dont know how. This funcionallity is coming from library KVKCalendar. Can you give some more explenation on that? Any minimal working example? I am new in swift programming. @Paulw11